# Open Source Multimedia Gallery

Tags: open-source, web-apps, media-manager, gallery

I need to find an **open source web-app** that fits (or can be enhanced to fit) the following requirements:

- Multimedia gallery, that displays at least a thumbnail for audio, video, image, web docs, pdf, etc; directly playing is a bonus;
- Allows both uploading the files or inserting metadata from other sources, like youtube, soundcloud, issuu, vimeo, etc.
- Provides good support for metadata (categories, tags, )
- Provides advanced and faceted search
- Can be hosted in a Unix server (where we can install necessary requirements)

My first approach was to search for Wordpress plugins that could do the job, like Gmedia, and Nimble for multimedia. However, faceted searching in Wordpress looks still in its infancy. Moreover, I fell like I don't need the whole wordpress for this.

A Python Django solution sounds good, since it has good support for connecting with search engines like solr. However, I did not find any existing tools.

Some inspirations (at least for the interface) are:

- [World Digital Library](https://www.wdl.org/en/)
- [Archive.ORG](https://archive.org/details/@articula_o_no_semi_rido_brasileiro&tab=collections)

but none of them provide the code.

Any ideas appreciated!

Comment: What I have in mind is a self-hosted web-app, on a unix machine, where I have access to install the necessary tools. Thanks, I'll edit the question.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Alan! I gave it some additional polish (hope that's fine with you). Good luck then!

Comment: https://mediagoblin.org/ ?